# Access 2007 - Query displays Combobox Primary ID rather than Value

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2007

I am writing a query based on a Table which is populated via a Form with several combo boxes. The information is stored in the Table as the Primary Key of the Combobox value which I understand to be correct.  However, when I run a query or report based on the Table, I would like to display the Combo box Value rather than the Primary Key ID.  Is there a way to do this other than using a Lookup to the combobox in the Table?

Thanks in advance for your help.

JB

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have your combo boxes set up.  Are they populated from a list in the field or from another table?

If from a list you entered in the table field where the value is stored, you should just store the value.

If they are from a separate table, then set the relationship from the combo lookup table's primary key/ID to a field in the main table that stores the combo selection which should be a number type.  In a query, add both your main table and the other table where values for the combo are stored and add the value to your results from the combo value table along with the data from your main table.

Comment: It is almost never a good idea to use look-up fields in tables. The only time it can be useful is on sharepoint, otherwise, they lead to misery.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little confusing to say you want to query a combobox value, essentially you need to look at the SQL source of the combobox first in order to see where it draws it's values from.  You then need to link this back to your query that you are running, as long as there is a common PK/FK between these then you can just perform an INNER JOIN on that.